# How to use Java Tester as well as the main Java Class for Fractions such as Half or Quarter

Tags: java

I've been stuck on 4.6.6 on [CodeHS](https://codehs.com/). Could someone please help me out? This is the code I currently have. It keeps having some issues with constructors, or something of that sort. I think the logic is correct, but I am making some silly mistake.

```
public class Fraction {
  private int numerator();
  private int denominator();

  public int getNumerator() {
    return numerator();
  }

  public int getDenominator() {
    return denominator();
  }

  public void setNumerator(int x) {
    numerator = x;
  }

  public void setDenominator(int x) {
    denominator = x;
  }
}
```

In the tester I have:

```
public class FractionTester extends ConsoleProgram {

  public void run() {
    Fraction half = new Fraction(1,2);
    System.out.println(half.getNumerator());

    Fraction quarter = new Fraction(1,4);
    System.out.println(quarter);
  }
}
```

Comment: `private int numerator();` is wrong: it's just `numerator`, without the brackets, both here are in the getters.

Comment: You'll also want to override toString in your Fraction class for your System.out.println()s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have a constructor in your Fraction class.

Add the following:

```
public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {

    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = denominator;
}
```

That should help.

You also need to remove the parenthesis from your class attributes numerator and denominator.

```
private int numerator;
private int denominator;
```